# почему пропадает атрибут в динамически сформированном элементе

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#mySelect').change(function () {
        //var typeFeed = $("#mySelect option:selected").text();
        var option = $("#mySelect option:selected");
        var text = option.text();
        //alert(text);
                    if (!(text === 'Материал'))
                    {
                        $('#ddl_material').append('<div class="ddl-cont-item" data-id="12">' + text + '</div>');

                        var selector=$(".ddl-cont-item");
                        FillMaterialFilter(selector);
                        RenderItems(postData);
                        option.detach();
                    }
    });
```

В сгенерированной разметке `data-id` пропадает.

Я уже просто написал `data-id`, для теста.

Пытался сделать `onclick="myFunction();` Класс остается. Остальные все атрибуты удаляются.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Добавьте html, где Вы реализуете `onclick="myFunction();` и где `myFunction()` у Вас в коде jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#mySelect').change(function () {
  //var typeFeed = $("#mySelect option:selected").text();
  var option = $("#mySelect option:selected");
  var text = option.text();
  
  if (text !== 'Материал') {
    $('#ddl_material').append('<div class="ddl-cont-item" data-id="12">' + text + '</div>');

    var selector=$(".ddl-cont-item");
    //FillMaterialFilter(selector);
    //RenderItems(postData);
    option.detach();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<select name="name" id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Не материал</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Материал</option>
</select>

<div id="ddl_material"></div>
```